# Проблемы с запуском программы js в vscode

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, отладка

При дебаге простого кода "Hello world!" `js` в `vscode` при помощи Google, выводится следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**launch.json**:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы немного путаете использование debug в vscode. Вы должны запустить http сервер по адресу и порту http://localhost:8080 затем проверить его работу соединяясь под debug к chrome. Просто посмотрите несколько инструкций для создания и запуска веб сервера. Затем посмотрите его debug

Comment: я никогда не работал с js, поэтому вполне закономерно. спасибо